# 'DB Error: connect failed' when downloading podcast

Tags: bug, status-completed

In the footer there's a link to "[podcast](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html)". It seems to be broken - when you click on it, you get:

> DB Error: connect failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, issue with http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/ , it seems. Hopefully temporary, but outside our control!